# Angularjs - generic factories

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

I understand how you declare a factory off of a module.

```
//Example:
var myModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
myModule.factory('myFactory', function () {  });
//and so on...
```

My question is:

How can I go about declaring a factory in a generic way?

I would like to have a way of writing factories portable enough so I don't have to say `module.factory`.  I just want to be able to drop a pre-made factory in a project without having to add it to a module and reference it as a dependency within a controller or what have you.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What are you wanting to accomplish with this?

Comment: I want to be able to write a factory I can use across all of my projects without having to explicitly attach it to a module.

Comment: Then you should create a module. Have your other projects (apps?) include that module as a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is write a separate module that your factory is attached to and then include that module in your main module. Then you can use that factory in your controller

Comment: Ok, I appreciate this.  Is this a common practice?  Giving you the answer for being first.

Comment: Yes, that what the module is for.

Comment: Thanks.  Still putting the pieces together.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, the module system **IS** what makes services easily "droppable" into an app. First, you should know that the module declaration is chainable, so you can do:

```
angular
  .module('myApp.ExampleService', []);
  .factory('ExampleService', function () { 
    // Do something...
  });
```

So in your controller you can do this:

```
angular
  .module('myApp', ['myApp.ExampleService'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['ExampleService', function(ExampleService) {
    // Do something...
  });
```

See **[ng-boilerplate](https://github.com/ianwalter/ng-boilerplate)** for a working example.

Comment: I appreciate the extra info.  +1 for your time and effort.  Thank you!  I didn't know you could load the dependency like that (`myApp.Something`).  Great to know!

Comment: Thanks, yea you can name a module anything, I like to think of it as analogous to namespacing.